# API расписания транспорта Яндекс.Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В приложении и на сайте яндекс карт есть возможность узнать время прибытия на каждую остановку для каждого автобуса/троллейбуса/трамвая и т.д. Хочу создать бота для быстрого получения времени прибытия конкретного маршрута, однако на сайте с документацией не могу найти такую функцию.

Есть ли вообще такое API у Яндекса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, информация о перемещении транспорта по API Яндекса не поставляется.